# How to get correct json output in this case?

Tags: php, json

this is the $distribution array

```
Array
(
    [ASCM72X36] => Array
        (
            [item_code] => ASCM72X36
            [quantity] => 5
            [selling_price] => 6758.00
        )

    [ASCM72X48] => Array
        (
            [item_code] => ASCM72X48
            [quantity] => 5
            [selling_price] => 
        )

    [ASCM72X60] => Array
        (
            [item_code] => ASCM72X60
            [quantity] => 5
            [selling_price] => 8544.00
        )
)
```

and this is the $sold array

```
    Array
    (
        [ASCM72X36] => Array
            (
                [item_code] => ASCM72X36
                [quantity] => 1.0
            )

        [ASCM72X60] => Array
            (
                [item_code] => ASCM72X60
                [quantity] => 1.0
            )
)
```

so im comparing keys and building new $responce array with new quantity and filter out quantity 0 products like below

```
    $i=0;
    foreach($distribution as $key => $new_distribution)
    {
      $newqty = $new_distribution['quantity'] - $sold[$key]['quantity'];
      if( $newqty != 0 && $new_distribution['selling_price'] != ""){
        $responce->data[$i]['item_code'] = $new_distribution['item_code'];
        $responce->data[$i]['quantity'] = $newqty;
        $responce->data[$i]['selling_price'] = $new_distribution['selling_price'];
      }
    $i++;

}
```

then i need to get json encode out put so im doing it like this

```
echo json_encode($responce);
```

im getting out put like

```
{"data":{"0":{"item_code":"ASCM72X36","quantity":4,"selling_price":"6758.00"},"2":{"item_code":"ASCM72X60","quantity":4,"selling_price":"8544.00"}}}
```

problem is im getting a "0", "2" etc.. in json. how to prevent that and get the out put like without those "0" s and "2" etc...?

```
{"data":{"item_code":"ASCM72X36","quantity":4,"selling_price":"6758.00"},{"item_code":"ASCM72X60","quantity":4,"selling_price":"8544.00"}}
```

Comment: The 0 and 2 from what I can see are the array indices for the "data" array. Why are you wanting to remove them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting indices because you're skipping values. i.e., your array is associative, not numeric.

Try running

```
$responce->data = array_values($responce->data)
```

At the end to reindex it.  Better yet, drop the `[$i]` in your assignments and just do

```
$responce->data[] = ....
```

Also, you're spelling "response" wrong.

If none of that works, take a look at `JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK` if you're running PHP 5.3.3 or higher. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Answer (score 2):

seems that you are encoding the object.
the way you want you must encode the data variable

```
 echo json_encode(array("data"=>$responce->data));
```

If your encode an array that has strings as indices, the array becomes an object in the json encoded string.

Plase, try this way:

```
foreach($distribution as $key => $new_distribution)
{
  $newqty = $new_distribution['quantity'] - $sold[$key]['quantity'];
  if( $newqty != 0 && $new_distribution['selling_price'] != ""){
    $arr=array();
    $arr['item_code'] = $new_distribution['item_code'];
    $arr['quantity'] = $newqty;
    $arr['selling_price'] = $new_distribution['selling_price'];
    $responce->data[] = $arr;
  }
```

}

Comment: +1. This is it. Next time try to write in proper letter case, because you will look cool, right? Right! :)

Comment: thing is i need the data {"data":{ part. if i do as you said it removes that.

Comment: still no change array indices are still there

Comment: Then, must be some problem with your object array variable, what php version are you using? check the new code if works.